# How to delete all messages in the message window programmatically?

Tags: front-end, notebooks

By evaluating some Mathematica commands, I wish to get the equivalent effect as selecting `Delete All Messages` on the message window.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can obtain the [`NotebookObject`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NotebookObject) corresponding to the messages window using `MessagesNotebook`, and then delete all the cells using [`NotebookDelete`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NotebookDelete):

```
NotebookDelete @ Cells @ MessagesNotebook[]
```

Comment: Thank you very much indeed !

Answer (score 11):

You can also do what the button in messages notebook does:

```
FrontEndExecute[
  { 
    FrontEndToken[FrontEnd`MessagesNotebook[], "SelectAll"], 
    FrontEndToken[FrontEnd`MessagesNotebook[], "Clear"]
  }
]
```

The advantage is that it may not require kernel to run at all because all symbols are known by the front end. So this will work:

```
Button["test", (*our code*), Evaluator -> None ]
```